# Warming:The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<AppName>.app/<AppName>: setCenterPoint: setDetailType

Tags: ios

Today, I tried to submit an update to my app to the store using Xcode 5 and it gave the the warning The app references non-public selectors in Payload/.app/: setCenterPoint: setDetailType.

I'm using BaiduMap Sdk v2.1.0 library and I'm not useing private Api.What could be the problem? How can I fix it? The app is ganna be reject ? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like `setCenterPoint:setDetailType:` is a private method and needs to be a public method.

Comment: Find where `setCenterPoint:` is used and change the code sos it does not use it. You might want to check and see if "Baidu Sdk v2.1.0" is using `setCenterPoint:` Btw, providing more of the exact rejection message might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,Btw I haven't any way to fix this problem